# How do I change css class of parent if input field is focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

im trying to make a search box with a magnifying glass icon that becomes blue when the input field is focused.

the MagnifyingGlass component inherits its color from its parent element.

```
import styles from './Search.module.sass';
import { useState } from 'react';
import MagnifyingGlass from '../../icons/MagnifyingGlass';


const Search = () => {
  

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.searchWrapper}>
      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className={styles.searchInput}
        type='text'
        placeholder='Waar bent u naar opzoek?'
     
      />
      <span> // needs to contain a className that results in the color to change
        <MagnifyingGlass size='small' /> // inherits color from parent
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Search;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change any class on the parent element, you can just use the css `:focus-within` pseudo-selector.

According to MDN the `:focus-within CSS` pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused.

Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.wrapper:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper p {
  color: green;
}

.wrapper:focus-within p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>this is a text</p>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

You can read more about it [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) or [here on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/)